# install4j force update between version changes

Tags: install4j

I'm using the install4j with the auto update option and silent version check enabled. This works well when I increment the version. However, is there a way to invoke the update when the version hasn't changed? Sometimes there are releases between official releases for one or two users that I don't want to force upon everyone. I want to be able to somehow force the silent version auto updater checker to update when the updates.xml remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic on whether or not to download an update is fully customizable. On the "Installer->Screens & actions" step, open the updater and look for an action named "Update descriptor" entry. This is a "Set a variable" action that returns null if there is no update and an instance of `com.install4j.api.update.UpdateDescriptorEntry` if there is an update.

In the script of that action, you can add your special logic.

Comment: That is helpful, thanks! I still need a shortcut to the updater installed. I've looked all around and I don't see a way of making a custom shortcut to the launcher. It only lets me create shortcuts to installed files which doesn't include the updater in the Screens & Actions tab.

Comment: I created a standalone updater for this purpose along with a shortcut to it (couldn't select it but gave a relative path and file name). I can customize the logic, but the update descriptor has null entries since the version is technically the same thing. I can get around this by hard coding entries.

Comment: How do you decide if there is new release then? If the version is the same, then there's no point in downloading anything.